# How can I change this Jquery function (toggle)

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show, html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".open_list").hide();
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("800");
   });
});
 </script>
```

I'm doing a list with some hide div in it and i did this jquery function to do so. 
The thing is that this function makes that when you click on the trigger link it will show you the div that follows to open_list.

I'm looking for another function that allows me the same thing but that activates the div that follows .open_list but with a determinated class.

So it will ignore the divs that follow the open_list that don't have that class on them.

I have been doing all day with this and i can't find the right way to do this. Anyone who knows it please?

so I put the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".open_list").hide();
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active").nextAll('.campaigns_list').slideToggle("800");
});
```

});

But still don't work. I need the h1 doesn't move at all when the divs are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nextAll()` filtered by your selector, then grab the `first()` element of that list:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").nextAll('.yourClass').first().slideToggle("800");
});
```

The problem you were probably running into is that if you do `next('.yourClass')` no elements will be returned if the very next sibling isn't the one with `.youClass`

Comment: `.open_list` is the sibling of `.trigger`, not `.yourClass`.  Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PH537/2/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the jQuery traversal methods (`next`, `parent`, etc.) take an optional selector parameter:

```
$(this).nextAll('.someclass').first().slideToggle(800);
```

This code will select siblings of the element that have the class `someclass`, and perform the `slideToggle` animation.

Comment: I think that the next() function can select only nearby sibling - parameter is just filter. You must use nextAll() function to get all simblings

Answer (score 1):

it's really simple - just don't use next() but nextAll()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open_list").hide();
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active").nextAll('.yourClass').slideToggle("800");
    });
  });
</script>
```

If you want to select just one element, append ".eq(0)" after the .nextAll() function.

Hope I helped you. Best regards, Jakub.

Comment: well...you know it's not working this. but thanks for your help, i'll update the wustion so i can explain myself better

Comment: dude, it works perfectly ;) If you think that it doesn't then please explain details :)

Comment: I think that you didn't explain it correctly. What about this code ? http://jsfiddle.net/PH537/5/ If it is not what you want then please specify what you want. Thank you